# Multiline Textbox to Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a multi-line textbox with this appearance:

```
A#B
C#
D#E
```

and I want to populate my `datagridview` to something like this:

```
_________
|A|BC|D|E|
```

I mean, I want to split when there's a "#" , but I don't want multi-line cells in `datagridview`.

I tried this code:

```
Dim sup() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbCr, vbLf, vbTab, " "c, "#")
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(sup(0), sup(1), sup(2),sup(3))
```

but it says it goes outta bounds ... Thanks!

edit:
"Index out of range exception" Error.

If i paste the textbox values to microsoft word they come like this:
[image: textbox to word]

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint on the `Rows.Add()` line and inspected the array?

Comment: What do you mean with breakpoint?

Comment: [How to set a simple breakpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k80ex6de(v=vs.100).aspx) --- [Using breakpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx) --- [Breakpoints and debugging tools](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets5p6.html)

Comment: Where does that lead me?

Comment: It will help you inspect your values and variables while debugging. You can see the contents of the array at the moment when the breakpoint is hit, which can help you by telling you which parts have been split up or not.

Comment: If you place a breakpoint on the `Rows.Add()` line you will be able to inspect the contents of the array, by expanding it's node in the `Locals` or `Autos` window/tab.

Comment: i did that but all i can see is `length=1` . Nothing usefull i guess..

Comment: No that is indeed useful! It tells you that the array only contains one string. So the split seems to never have been performed. If you press the plus `+` you will see the string inside at element `(0)`.

Comment: If the split fails when no delimiter is found, it will create an array containing only the input string.

Comment: "1-dimensional array of string cannot be converted to string"

Comment: Where do you get that error? Is it in the first item of the array?

Comment: yes ! but it only appears if i try to only add one row

Comment: and if i use the split method but "output" it in another textbox, it gives me "System.String[]"

Comment: i added an answer btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer4.Tick
    If DataGridView1.RowCount = 1 Then DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    Call dgvstuff()
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub


Sub dgvstuff()
    Dim sup2 = TextBox2.Text.Replace("#", "").Replace(">", " "c)
    Dim sup() = sup2.Split(" "c, "#", vbCrLf, vbTab)

    With DataGridView1
        .Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = sup(1).ToString
        .Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = sup(7).ToString
        .Rows(0).Cells(3).Value = sup(4).ToString
    End With
End Sub
```

I really don't know why but it works like this. Anyone knows a better/cleaner way? Tks

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you will be splitting your textbox with 3 #'s, you could use something like this after creating 3 columns in your datagridview

```
Dim myStr As String
Dim substring As String
Dim strArray() As String
Dim columnInt as Integer = 0

myStr = Textbox1.Text 
strArray = myStr.Split("#")

For i = 0 to strArray.Length - 1
Datagridview.Rows(0).Cells(columnInt).Value = strArray(i)
columnInt += 1
next
```

As I am not quite sure how you want this data to appear exactly, you may also need to declare the count of your columns should it be larger than 3. Add this code before the first For Statement:

```
For i = 0 to strArray.Length - 1
DataGridView.Columns.Add("YourText","YourText")
Next
```

Untested but it should get you in the right spot!
*Edit: Updated after testing

Comment: i have the same error.. "Index Out of Range Exception" .

Comment: I've made a few changes but this runs perfectly after testing. Keep in mind I am not sure what you want to name your columns so in the "DatagridView.Columns.add() portion, insert how you want these columns to display as(First as Name for accessing that Column later,Second as whats shown to user). Keep in mind I assume you only need 1 row of data now.

Comment: nope, doesn't work that way. The textbox2.text is the output of a rs232 connection, it's weird. I was able to do it with a timer, i'll post my answer later. I don't think it's the best way, but it works

Comment: i added an answer btw!