# Textbox replace and split not working vb.net

Tags: vb.net, replace, split

I've been struggling **way too much** with simple things, like the one i'm posting.

I'm developing a UI in vb.net that gathers some information from a machine. The information is collected to a TextBox:

```
Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
    If Me.TextBox2.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim x As New SetTextCallBlack(AddressOf ReceivedText)
        Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
    Else
        Me.TextBox2.Text &= [text]
    End If
End Sub
```

Then i gather that information either to a datagridview or to some labels to display simple information.

```
Sub dgv()

    Dim sup2 = TextBox2.Text.Replace("#", "").Replace(">", " "c)
    Dim sup() = sup2.Split(" "c, "#", vbCrLf, vbTab)

    With DataGridView1
        .Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = sup(1).ToString
        .Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = sup(7).ToString
        .Rows(0).Cells(3).Value = sup(4).ToString
    End With
    Button5.Enabled = True
    Button6.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

This works just fine !!!

But when i try to populate the labels, with the code below, it just won't work!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Thread.Sleep(250)

    Dim final = TextBox2.Text.Replace("#", "").Replace("SN", " "c)
    Dim final2() = final.Split(" "c, "#", vbCrLf, vbTab)
    Label1.Text = final2(0).ToString
    Textbox2.Text= final2(0).ToString

End Sub
```

Can someone help me? The label gets no text.. and the textbox gets all of it.

Btw, the textbox is multiline and if i paste the text in microsoft word it comes with tabs and extra spaces.

Edit: printscreen from microsoft word below [ related to [Multiline Textbox to Datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431247/multiline-textbox-to-datagridview) ]

[image: wordprintscreen]

Edit2: This is so strange ..

If i do this

```
Label1.Text = "Testing" & TextBox2.Text
```

it only shows "Testing" on the label..

Comment: If you replace the # with an empty string, then why you try to split with # that is no more present in your string?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx). Once you have corrected the problems it points out (e.g. there is no overload of String.Split which takes (char, string, string, string) as arguments) you may find your program works.

Comment: @Steve i was testing some stuff ! Ofc it doesn't make sense like that !

Comment: @AndrewMorton i'll give it a try. brb

Comment: `OPTION STRICT ON` as suggested by @AndrewMorton, plus can you post a sample of text that is in your texbox when Button1 is clicked?

Comment: @PradeepKumar it's already ON ! It's on the question as an image now . Thank you

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint and see what Label1.Text contains after the assignment?

Comment: @the_lotus yes i did. it shows "" ! and final2().length =1 . And i've updated the question!

Comment: Don't use `+` when concatenating strings, use `&` instead.

Comment: @VisualVincent It leads no where anyway. Doesn't work both ways

Comment: I didn't say it would solve your problem, but in general you shouldn't use `+` for concatenating strings.

Comment: @VisualVincent oh right. what about my problem? i have no idea what's happening..

Comment: Neither do I, and I am currently in no position to test your code.

Comment: @VisualVincent And it ain't easy to test it because of the connection to the machine. If i place the textbox text manually it works properly.. All my hope is based on something like ".toString", for sure it is something not readable at the moment cause it's not showing with `Label1.Text = "Testing" & TextBox2.Text`

Comment: @noidea If there is a Chr(0) in the string somewhere, then although it should not make a difference, it is possible that something is erroneously mistaking it for a C-style end-of-string. I recommend that, instead of gathering the data in a textbox, you gather it in a string.

Comment: Since you said it has extra spaces, try String.Trim() to remove those.

Comment: @RoyalPotato i already have an answer for this. I have to post it later :) Thank you

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't realize this question was old ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the label to AutoSize, it will automatically grow with whatever text you put in it.  (This includes vertical growth.)

Before `assign` value to the `label1`,

Use the below code

```
Label1.MaximumSize = new Size(100, 0)
Label1.AutoSize = true
```

your code would be like

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Thread.Sleep(250)

    Dim final = TextBox2.Text.Replace("#", "").Replace("SN", " "c)
    Dim final2() = final.Split(" "c, "#", vbCrLf, vbTab)
    Label1.MaximumSize = new Size(100, 0)
    Label1.AutoSize = true
    Label1.Text = final2(0).ToString
    Textbox2.Text= final2(0).ToString

End Sub
```

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work.. Label shows no text and Textbox shows all of the text.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but i want to get rid of all the formattings . Question updated btw!